# Using only 1 System.out.print() instead of 3. More details below

Tags: java

Here are two variables:

```
    int number1 = 26;
    int number2 = 876;
```

How could i print out this sentence:
"Value of number1 is: 26 and value of number2 is: 876." , using only one print() function?

I could do this with 3 print() function :

```
    System.out.print("Value of number1: " + number1);
    System.out.print(" and value of number2: " + number2);
    System.out.print(".");
```

Altough i would like to use only 1 print() to do all of the above if it is possible

Comment: Concatenate your Strings. Keep using the `+` operator.

Comment: Another option... `print(String.format("Value of number1 is: %d and value of number2 is: %d.", number1, number2))`

Comment: `System.out.printf("Value of number1 is: %d and value of number2 is: %d.%n", number1, number2);` as a 3rd option

Comment: Oh so Java has the printf function which works just like Objective-C's NSLog by replacing format specifiers with variable's value. Good to know...

Comment: One more way is like shown here by using '+' as: System.out.println("Value of number1: " + number1+and value of number2: " + number2+".");